text_auto Parameter Not Working in Plotly
The text_auto parameter for a Plotly Express bar chart is not functioning for me, despite seemingly correct syntax. I am using both Jupyter Notebook and Eclipse and the issue persists in both. Plotly version 5.19.
I am attempting to create a bar chart using Ploty Express. I would like to display the top orders of the year for a theoretical pizza shop.
The following is what I am trying:
order_total_prices = df.groupby('order_id')['total_price'].sum().reset_index()
top_orders = order_total_prices.sort_values(by='total_price', ascending=False).head(20)
fig = px.bar(top_orders, x="order_id", y="total_price", labels={"order_id": "Order ID", 'total_price': "Total Price"}, title='What were the top orders of the year?', text_auto=True)
fig.show()

This is the output:

I ran a query in SSMS and confirmed that those are the correct order numbers and largest orders.
However, I would like the x-axis to be formatted like the following:

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

I can't pinpoint this as the cause since no data is presented, but is the data type of the order ID numerical? Try changing it from a numeric to a categorical variable with the following code. fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
